# How to connect to wifi without disabling powersave?

Tags: wireless

In order to connect to a WPA/WPA2, EAP-PEAP, MSCHAPV2-secured network, I always have to do `sudo iw wlp1s0 set power_save off`. Is there a way to fix it so I can both have my battery life and be connected to wifi?

Happy to supply whichever logs are useful.

Comment: What is your wireless adapter? What happens if you don't disable powersave?

Comment: I simply can't connect to the network with powersave on - it times out.  The wireless adapter is Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a).

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: It's Ubuntu 17.04